# dojox.form.Uploader 403 error from django server

Tags: django, dojo

I have a very simple form that I've added the uploader to.  When I invoke the uploader, django returns
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
This is the uploader:

```
            var ul = new Uploader(
            {
                label:"Programmed uploader",
                multiple:false,
                uploadOnSelect:true,
                url:Environment.apiRoot + "upload/",
                headers:{
                    "Accept" : "application/json",
                    "X-CSRFToken" : dojo.cookie("csrftoken")
                }
            }).placeAt(form);
```

I created simple "test" button that invokes a function that performs the same post.

```
            new Button({
                name:"Cancel2",
                //id:"Cancel",
                label:"Cancel" ,
                placement:"secondary",
                onClick:lang.hitch(this,function(event){
                    this._testpost()
                })
            }).placeAt(form);
```

This is the relavent header from the uploader post

Cookie  djdt=hide; csrftoken=WwlARc9OUevblKfgNEDU2Ae4eT9z0kos;sessionid=du37rjyam6v69mw0bgctkbw708xlvc5g

This is the _testpost()

```
    _testpost: function (){
        xhr.post({
            url: Environment.apiRoot + "upload/",
            handleAs: "json",
            postData: json.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept" : "application/json",
                "X-CSRFToken" : dojo.cookie("csrftoken")
            },
            loadingMessage: "Submitting  form..."
        }).then( 
            lang.hitch(this,function(result) {
                form = t._f_form;
                dojo.destroy(form);
                this._float.destroyRecursive();
                alert(result['result_text']);

                result['message'] = "Update Request Accepted";

            }),lang.hitch(this, function(err){
                form = t._f_form;
                dojo.destroy(form);
                this._float.destroyRecursive();
                topic.publish("/application/message","An error occurred.");
        }));
```

this is the relevant header from invoking the _testpost function

Cookie  djdt=hide; csrftoken=WwlARc9OUevblKfgNEDU2Ae4eT9z0kos;sessionid=du37rjyam6v69mw0bgctkbw708xlvc5g

X-CSRFToken WwlARc9OUevblKfgNEDU2Ae4eT9z0kos

The key difference being that in the _testpost the X-CSRFToken is put into the header, but on the Uploader post, I don't have any means to put in an X-CSRFToken (my headers attribute seems to just be ignored - i tried it to see if I could get this to work)

Is there any way to get additional headers into the Uploader

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, dojox.form.Uploader does not allow headers to be added.

There are a couple options. It sounds like you have access to the csrf token and could append it to the url. Another option may be to provide the csrf token as a cookie and it should be sent with XHR and Flash request.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done (and i'm not sure this is correct), within the django view, disabled csrf checking, and then pull the csrf value out of the header and compare it against the csrf value that is kept in the session record on the server.

Answer (score -1):

you may use `dojo.aspect` to add the headers to the `dojox.form.Uploader`.

In case you are using HTML5 upload "plugin", that looks like since you have left the default, you may use something like:

```
aspect.after(ul, "createXhr", function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", dojo.cookie("csrftoken"));
                return xhr;
            });
```

Add this just after you create the Uploader. Also remember to require `dojo/aspect`.

Notice that this is a bit of a hack and prone to breakage if some change happen in `dojox.form.Uploader` structure (e.g. they update it to use `dojo.promise` or other fixes). Also it's implied that this works only for HTML5 plugin, but you may extend the code in the same way to cope for other plugins by inspecting `ul.uploadType` and make the change specific for that plugin.

This solution works up to and including dojo version 1.12. In 2017 the above announced breakage did happen an this does not work anymore with version of dojo from 1.13 and upward.

Comment: This won't work because dojo does not use XHR to upload files but form submission

Comment: Hey @NicolasSeiller, this it is a working solution that I'm currently using in production. Have a look at the code and you will see (better doing that before down voting ;) ). As you will see in the code, or having a look at [Uploader docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/form/Uploader.html) there are various modes apart the "form" mode. I specified already that my solution works only with "HTML5" plugin. The only thing I noticed is that there is a typo and it's "dojox.form.Uploader" instead of "dojo.form.Uploader". Thing that I am going to fix.

Comment: @NicolasSeiller, here you can have a look at the function I'm patching (createXhr() ) https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/form/uploader/_HTML5

Comment: @NicolasSeiller and finally, you forgot to check the post date. The post was from Jun 2015, "createXhr" was removed from _HTML5.js in Apr 2017 so the solution was working up to and including dojo version 1.12. Here the link to the [code](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/7be8be97ddd461a92bf326dae39e927d98558b54/form/uploader/_HTML5.js#L121). The post already specifies in 2015 that the technique is "prone to breakage".It did worked for 2 years, enough time to fix the problem ;) I am kindly asking you to check your facts fully before posting (especially when necroposting on 4 years old answer)